# Jquery UI Tooltip take place in <TR> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

When i put Jquery UI tooltip on `td` element in table jquery creates 
`<div class="tooltip">` directly inside `tr` tag. This 'div' element takes some place in UI and shift td element on which it was applied a little bit to the left.

here is example code:

[image]

How to make tooltip do not take any place in tr

Answer (score 0):

A Better way is to create a `<div>` tag inside `<td>` and add tooltip to that `<div>`.

```
<td>
    <div class="tooltipTarget"></div>
<td>
```

Keep in mind that, you must not set padding to td